# How do I tell TikZ to compute the 'in' value again rather than use the previous one?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The first two lines do just what I want:

```
\node (F) at (1,1) {$F$};

\draw (0,2) to [out=-90] (F);
```

That is, it draws an edge downward from the point `(0,0)` and bends it to hit `(F)`, entering the node at roughly 135 degrees. I don't have to specify `in=135`.

But the next line uses the same ~135 degree value for `in`, when I want it to have a value around 45 degrees *and not specify it*!

```
\draw (2,2) to [out=-90] (F);
```

How do I tell `tikz` to compute the `in` value again rather than use the previous one?

Here's a minimum working example, modified now that it's clear I was a "victim of circuses":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw=black] (F) at (1,1) {$F$};
    \draw (0,2) to [out=-90] (F);
    \draw (0.7,2) to [out=-90, in=110] (F);
    \draw (2,2) to [out=-90, in=45] (F);
    \draw (F) to [out=-135, in=90] (0,0);
    \draw (F) to [out=-45, in=90] (2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've inserted the image, and will delete my comments. You can do the same to keep this space clean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are a victim of circuses.

The fact that you "don't have to specify `in=135`" is a coincidence.  And the conclusion that in the second case TikZ is "us[ing] the previous one" is false.  The observed behaviour is all due to two little lines in the file `tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex` which read:

```
\def\tikz@to@out{45}
\def\tikz@to@in{135}
```

These mean that if you don't specify an `out` then it is automatically set to `45`, similarly if you don't specify an `in` it is automatically set to `135`.  (These only have effect if *something* selects the `curve` variant of the `to path` rather than the default.  Specifying *one* of `in` or `out` is sufficient.)

There is a `relative` option which sets the angles relative to a line between the start and ending coordinates.  So if you use `relative,in=180` (as the line is oriented *from* the source *to* the target) then the correct angle is chosen for the `in` line.  However, this makes the `out` angle *also* relative, which isn't what you seem to want.

So here's a little code I wrote that sets the `in` and `out` automatically if you don't set them yourself.  The key, `auto ends`, has to be given *before* any overriding `out` or `in` because it can't tell the difference between the user saying `out=45` and the default value.  However, this does not seem much of a hardship.

What it does is to set both `in` and `out` to be empty at call time.  Then when the path is processed, any that are still empty are set to the angle between the start and end coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39903/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  auto ends/.code={%
    \def\tikz@to@switch@on{\let\tikz@to@path=\tikz@to@curve@path@rel}%
    \tikz@to@switch@on
    \let\tikz@to@in=\pgfutil@empty
    \let\tikz@to@out=\pgfutil@empty
  }
}

\def\tikz@to@curve@path@rel{%
  [every curve to]
  \pgfextra{%
    \ifx\tikz@to@out\pgfutil@empty
     \let\relin@toto=\tikztotarget
    \ifx\tikz@to@in\pgfutil@empty
    \else
     \tikz@to@modify\relin@toto\tikz@to@in
    \fi
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\relin@toto)\relax
     \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
     \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
     \advance\pgf@xa by -\pgf@x
     \advance\pgf@ya by -\pgf@y
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikz@to@out{int(atan2(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya))}%
    \fi
    \ifx\tikz@to@in\pgfutil@empty
     \let\relin@tofrom=\tikztostart
    \ifx\tikz@to@out\pgfutil@empty
    \else
     \tikz@to@modify\relin@tofrom\tikz@to@out
    \fi
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\relin@tofrom)\relax
     \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
     \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
     \advance\pgf@xa by -\pgf@x
     \advance\pgf@ya by -\pgf@y
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikz@to@in{int(atan2(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya))}%
    \fi
    \iftikz@to@relative
     \tikz@to@compute@relative
    \else
     \tikz@to@compute
    \fi
  }
  \tikz@computed@path \tikztonodes
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw=black] (F) at (1,1) {$F$};
    \draw (0,2) to [auto ends,out=-90] (F);
    \draw (2,2) to [auto ends,out=-90] (F);
    \draw (2,-2) to [auto ends,out=90] (F);
    \draw (-2,-2) to [auto ends] (F);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image: tikz to path with automatic angles]

---

Marc van Dongen and I have slightly different interpretations of the request.  Here's an adaptation of the above code that allows for syntax of the form:

```
\draw[every to/.style={auto ends}] (0,2) to [out=-90]  (F) to[intermediate,in=-90] (2,2);
```

The reason for the needed code is that if one writes something like:

```
\draw (0,0) to[out=90,in=45] (F) to[out=90,in=45] (0,2);
```

then the result is not the same as writing

```
\draw (0,0) to[out=90,in=45] (F) (F) to[out=90,in=45] (0,2);
```

Witness:

[image: to paths]

The point is that a `to path` constructs a new piece of a path which is *appended* to the current path.  So in the above, the construction results in something like `.. controls (some point) and (some other point) .. (the target)`.  Now `(the target)` might well have been modified from what was originally specified on the path.  But the source was not mentioned in the additional part (this makes sense for concatenating paths segments).  So the result of two successive `to` paths is something like:

```
.. controls (1st cntrl) and (2nd cntrl) .. (1st modified target) .. controls (3rd cntrl) and (4th cntrl) .. (2nd modified target);
```

In particular, the *source* for the second `to path` is *not* what was specified in the original `\draw` command but is what the first `to path` said it was.  **Most of the time** this is exactly what is wanted.  However, to do the original poster's path *in one go*, this isn't what is wanted.  There, what is wanted is the second behaviour where the result would be:

```
.. controls (1st cntrl) and (2nd cntrl) .. (1st modified target) (1st original target) .. controls (3rd cntrl) and (4th cntrl) .. (2nd modified target);
```

To achieve this automatically, we need to reinsert the original target back in the stream.  However, we can't do this automatically at the end of the first to path since we don't know that there is a second to path on its way.  All we can do at the end of the first one is to save the original target just in case it is needed again.  Then at the start of the second, we can reuse it (if we want) to restart the path again at the correct place.

Here's the modified code, with an example.  As written, it is tied in to the `auto ends` key, but it could easily be extracted to a separate set of keys.  The difficulty is that the standard `to path`s would need patching to to insert the correct move to.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39903/86}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  auto ends/.code={%
    \def\tikz@to@switch@on{\let\tikz@to@path=\tikz@to@curve@path@rel}%
    \tikz@to@switch@on
    \let\tikz@to@in=\pgfutil@empty
    \let\tikz@to@out=\pgfutil@empty
    \let\relin@start=\pgfutil@empty
  },
  intermediate/.code={
    \let\relin@start=\relin@target
  },
}

\newif\ifrelin@restartnext
\newif\ifrelin@restart

\def\tikz@to@curve@path@rel{%
  [every curve to]
  \pgfextra{%
    \global\let\relin@target=\tikztotarget
    \ifx\relin@start\pgfutil@empty
    \else
    \let\tikztostart=\relin@start
    \fi
    \ifx\tikz@to@out\pgfutil@empty
     \let\relin@toto=\tikztotarget
    \ifx\tikz@to@in\pgfutil@empty
    \else
     \tikz@to@modify\relin@toto\tikz@to@in
    \fi
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\relin@toto)\relax
     \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
     \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
     \advance\pgf@xa by -\pgf@x
     \advance\pgf@ya by -\pgf@y
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikz@to@out{int(atan2(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya))}%
    \fi
    \ifx\tikz@to@in\pgfutil@empty
     \let\relin@tofrom=\tikztostart
    \ifx\tikz@to@out\pgfutil@empty
    \else
     \tikz@to@modify\relin@tofrom\tikz@to@out
    \fi
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\relin@tofrom)\relax
     \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
     \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
     \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
     \advance\pgf@xa by -\pgf@x
     \advance\pgf@ya by -\pgf@y
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\tikz@to@in{int(atan2(\pgf@xa,\pgf@ya))}%
    \fi
    \iftikz@to@relative
     \tikz@to@compute@relative
    \else
     \tikz@to@compute
    \fi
    \ifx\relin@start\pgfutil@empty
    \else
    \let\relin@computed@path=\tikz@computed@path
    \edef\tikz@computed@path{(\relin@start)\tikz@computed@path}
    \fi
  }
  \tikz@computed@path \tikztonodes
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw=black] (F) at (1,1) {$F$};
\draw[every to/.style={auto ends}] (0,2) to[out=-90] (F) to[intermediate,in=-90] (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: tikz to path with intermediate node]

Comment: The original poster asked for a solution where he could specify two end points and an intermediate point. In your solution, the intermediate point has to be specified twice, which is a form of over-specification that can (and should) be avoided because it will lead to user errors in the long run.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen That's not my reading of the question.  Maybe it's ambiguous.  I read it as that the last code (the MWE) would be fine if the `in=45` could be omitted.

Comment: That's fine, but can you make the solution better? In my solution I also implemented the requirements but I had to revert to a new command, which is awkward. It would be _much_ nicer if you could write `\draw (source) to[via={intermediate node specification},in=degree] (destination);`. I lacked the TikZ skills to do this. (There still is hope I will some time learn.:-)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I've added an option for the intermediate part, together with an explanation of why it doesn't *just work*.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not convinced a solution isn't possible.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen (whoops, that vote on your comment was me by mistake.  Not that it isn't a great comment ...).  I clearly don't understand the problem that you are trying to solve.  I think it is distinct from what Mike is asking for, so why don't you ask it as a fresh question?  Then you'll have more space to flesh out what the exact specifications are (refer back to this question for "history", of course).

Comment: I'd like to avoid overspecification. It shouldn't be necessary to specify things that can be computed from other things. For example, why should the user have to specify the ``intermediate point'' twice? I think we can avoid it. Once we have to solution, we can reuse it for similar problems.

Comment: Yeah, Marc's initial reading was what I had in mind.  I just want to impose Dirichlet conditions on the input and output wires for F.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I still don't get it.  Where in my (second) solution does the user have to specify the intermediate point twice?

Comment: @MikeStay As can happen with Dirichlet conditions, the problem is not precisely specified.  Would you like to be able to type what Mark has in his first code block?  That's an easy adaptation of the above code.

Comment: Yes, the first block looks like just what I want.  However, I tried to use it and I got the error
   Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `int'.
Is there some package I need to use?

Comment: @Andrew Your second solution is fine, but you claim it _just doesn't work_:-)

Comment: Here's some more context on what I'm trying to do: https://plus.google.com/103343818035969600812/posts/AWnHhpLzWe3  You'll note that all the strings are smooth except around f.

Comment: @MikeStay You will need to upgrade TikZ/PGF to version 2.10 (at least).  It's well worth doing anyway - there's a question on this site about how to upgrade TikZ/PGF, just ask if it's not clear how to do it (best to ask in chat rather than here as there are more people who will be able to help you more quickly).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Sorry, it was clear in my mind what I meant by that comment but now I re-read it I can see that it isn't clear.  What I meant by "doesn't just work" is that the *naive* attempt doesn't work; that would be trying `\draw (a) to[out=90,in=90] (b) to[out=-90,in=90] (c);` doesn't do what one might expect it to.  My solution above *does* work.  The only bit that seems not what you want is that it is as two `to` paths instead of just one.  But that would be easy to fix.

Comment: @MikeStay I guess you want to replace those lines like `\draw (-1.5, -3) to (F);` with `\draw (-1.5,-3) to[auto ends,out=-90] (F);` to smooth them out, no?  (Which looks awfully like *my* interpretation, not Marc's.)  Incidentally, you could rewrite your program in TeX to enable you to write `\composition r_B o (B l_I) o a_((B I) I) o (f_[(A I), (B I)] I) o a'_((A I) I) o (A l'_I) o r'_A: A -> B;` to render it.  Search here for "braids" to get an idea of what bizarre things are possible with TeX and TikZ.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I've done that---at least, `texdoc pgf` pulls up the manual for 2.10.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Sorry about the misattribution!  I did, at least, mark your solution as the right answer.  Regarding "you could rewrite your program in TeX"---sure, if I knew TeX!  I wrote that program in javascript, since that's what I've been using for the past four years at work.

Comment: @MikeStay (and Marc) let's continue this in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Answer (score 2):

You have the simple solution :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw=black] (F) at (1,1) {$F$};
    \draw (0,2) to [out=-90] (F);
    \draw (F) to [in=-90] (2,2) ;
  \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does qualify as a solution if you always have the same `in` and `out` values. In general, this is not the case. For example, if you want a different `in` value, you have to make _two_ changes, in the code.

Comment: Here we have the same values but if you have different values I use  `out=45` and `out=135` with `(F)` and If you need four defined values, I think the best it's to write them.

Comment: Surely it's not better to repeat them. First of all you make errors when you copy the values. Second, you may make errors when you're computing the ``opposite' `in` and `out` values: if one `in=1.432565626764` then you don't want to compute the other `in` by hand. It's not a convenient API. Even if you want to change the intermediate point, you have to make two edit operations. (Not great for maintenance.)

Comment: This happens to work because of the choice of angles.  The defaults for `in` and `out` are 135 and 45 respectively.